# Smartmontools possibilities

Tags: hardware

Does smartmontools have a possibility do send specific command? For example, READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS. If it is possible how to do that?

Reading the manual didn't give me anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, smartctl cannot do that.

If you want to know true physical disk size, you should use `hdparm -N`.

Comment: Strange thing is that sometimes smartctl give a response with errors, where you can find part of the commands, but it seems that they are still not sending.

Comment: Error 6 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 960 hours (40 days + 0 hours)

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  10 51 01 af f8 50 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  -------------
  37 00 01 af f8 50 40 00      01:05:06.949  SET MAX ADDRESS EXT
  27 00 00 00 00 00 40 00      01:05:06.948  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS

Comment: These commands were NOT sent by smartctl itself. What this message literally means is some disk error happened when disk was trying to execute SET MAX ADDRESS command. This error message was simply retrieved by smartctl from disk SMART error buffer

Comment: I compiled smartmontools and print the values what they send, but SET MAX ADDRESS command is not sending to the device, it is only IDENTIFY DEVICE and some SMART commands.

Comment: And moreover about hdparm. I had a look to this tool, but I couldn't send it, because I have a RAID controller, and hdparm support commands, which are sending straight away to the disk

Comment: That's what I said in the beginning - smartctl does NOT ever send SET MAX ADDRESS command. Error message you are seeing is simply contents of smart error buffer. It is difficult to say who actually send this command - it could have been RAID controller itself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering. But maybe you know some other tools, which have functionality of sending these commands except smartmontools and hdparm?

Comment: Not that I know of. But, you could develop that yourself - that's the beauty of open source :-)